# Other than chromecast from google, is it possible to build my own google cast receiver with google cast SDK?

Tags: google-cast

I'm wondering if I can build a cast reviver device like chromecast from google? From the google cast sdk it seems only chromecast can be a receiver device, am I understanding correctly?

Comment: Some apps for Android will use `RemotePlaybackClient` on the client side, rather than the proprietary Cast SDK. You could create a `MediaRouteProvider` that forwards media requests to a receiver device that you create. Then, any app that uses `RemotePlaybackClient` will be able to work with your device, assuming that the phone or tablet has your `MediaRouteProvider` app on it. [This directory](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MediaRouter) contains sample projects for implementing `MediaRouteProvider` and connecting to it from `RemotePlaybackClient`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot build your own version of Chromecast device if you want to use the official Cast SDK; the official SDK verifies that it is talking to a genuine cast device.

Comment: How does one build a "genuine cast device"? How can HW manufacturers implement cast into their devices?