# Can I port google cast sdk on my linux development board so that it acts as cast receiver?

Tags: raspberry-pi, google-cast

I cannot build my own google cast receiver device (like chromecast device) as of now correct ?
I read this post many days ago but wanted to double confirm its still the same

[Other than chromecast from google, is it possible to build my own google cast receiver with google cast SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25598986/other-than-chromecast-from-google-is-it-possible-to-build-my-own-google-cast-re)

I was wondering if google allows option to port the sdk on raspberry pi (or any linux development platform with required connectivity), so that i can make this development board as google cast receiver and stream the music and videos from my android phone.

Comment: "I cannot build my own google cast receiver device (like chromecast device) as of now correct ?" -- no, but you are welcome to implement a `MediaRouteProvider`. This provides the connection between Android apps using `RemotePlaybackClient` and devices like your proposed one. You would still be responsible for implementing media playback on the Pi, but existing Android apps using `RemotePlaybackClient` could send the Pi media to be played back, by means of your `MediaRouteProvider`.

Comment: Thanks for the info, In this case 
1. support MediaRouteProvider can be implemented on linux target ? The information i found suggests it uses android packages , I think that is  only hostside (I mean Android phone side) framework .
OR do i need to port android on my target device to support it ?

I have media playback capable target board with wifi running linux

2. Do i need any any certification from google to market such device ?

Comment: Following google developers link says MediaRouteProvider is android interface and needs to be implemented in target. This indicates i need to have android on my target platform. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarouteprovider.html
Please Correct me if otherwise

Comment: "Following google developers link says MediaRouteProvider is android interface and needs to be implemented in target" -- no. `MediaRouteProvider` is an Android interface and it is implemented on the client device. The app there would fill a role similar to what the Chromecast app does for Chromecast. In fact, the Chromecast app implements a `MediaRouteProvider`, in addition to (presumably) providing support for the proprietary Cast API.

Comment: "Do i need any any certification from google to market such device ?" -- not that I am aware of, any more than you need certification from Google to have an app on a phone talk to a toaster, or to a security system, or to a robot.

Answer (score 0):

The response given in the referenced post is still valid. In addition, currently there are no plans to extend the support to Raspberry PI.